# How does gcore handle multithreaded program?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcore

There is a program called `gcore` that can create coredump file of a running process.

But how does it take **consistent** snapshots of memory in case of multi threaded program?

Comment: gcore creates a snapshot of the memory for all the target running programs, stopping all their threads when doing, so what inconsistencies do you speak about ?

Comment: All threads in a program execute within the *same* address space. If they did not, they would be in separate processes. So, if you take a snapshot of a process address space, that will, by definition, snapshot the address space of all threads. The *definition* of a thread is more or less, a separate thread of execution *within* the same address space as all other threads of the process. If they had different address spaces, they wouldn't be threads, they'd be different processes.

Comment: I'm sorry, guys, I thought that during snapshotting some of threads are still running. That's why I asked about consistency.

Comment: @kirugan fortunately this is not the case, else yes the result cannot be used

Comment: Isn't gcore just a script that invokes gdb and tells it to stop the process (all its threads) and dump its memory/state?

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I've just checked that with "cat `which gcore`" seems like it's just a bash script with gdb invocation. Thanks!